# How can I judge whether the contents of the variable have been macro-defined?

Tags: c++, c, macros

`#ifdef` can be used to determine whether a string is a macro definition. But I have several macro definitions, how do I judge whether the content of the variable has been macro defined.
for example,

```
char *str = "Macro"
#ifdef  (*str)
```

Is there a way to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Why do you need this? Also your code doesn't have any macros.

Comment: No, I need a lot of macros to set some flags. When I want to set a bit, I can simply use #define bit_name

Comment: Oh, you want `#ifdef (*str)` to act as `#ifdef Macro`? It's not possible.

Comment: So what I'm talking about is is there a similar method that can be achieved? similiar?

Comment: Stop using macros for things it's not meant for. You should generally keep the use of macros to a minimum, and what you want here is clearly not a macro. You can use templates and constexpr functions to make compile-time checks.

Comment: You are right. I have tried to use array or enum instead

Comment: "...determine whether a string is a macro definition" No. You cannot pass a string to `ifdef`. A string would have enclosing quotes. What you mean is an identifier, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *str = "Macro"
#ifdef  (*str)
```

That will never work, as `str` is no macro! The syntax for `*str` will not be accepted by the preprocessor. BTW: In C++ `char *str = "Macro"` is also wrong, as you must use `const char*`!

In general: Avoid macros as they are error prone. They have no type and they are part of some text replacement functionality, far away from types in C++.

> how do I judge whether the content of the variable has been macro defined

There is no `variable` in the sense of the preprocessor. And you can't check c++ variables in the preprocessor, because the preprocessor has no knowledge about C or C++ at all. It is only a more or less simple text replacement tool which runs before the C++ code itself will be parsed by the compiler, even if both parts, the preprocessor and the the C++ parser are physically in the same program.

> So what I'm talking about is is there a similar method that can be achieved?

No! You can't check if a variable exists or not. If it is not existing, you always get a compile error. You can check the value or the type of a variable e.g. with SFINAE, but not the existence of a var itself.

But what is the real use case? Your questions shows us, how you think you would something realize, but not why and what?